# How __align__ works in cuda C?

Tags: cuda, memory-alignment

I am practicing an exercise for Array of Struct `(AoS)`. A *struct* with/without `__align__` has been defined like:

```cpp
#ifdef TESTALIGN8
struct __align__(8) InnerStruct {
    float x;
    float y;
};
#else
struct InnerStruct {
    float x;
    float y;
};
#endif
```

The test case is

```c
__global__ void testGpuInnerStruct(InnerStruct *data, InnerStruct *result, const int n) {
    unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (idx < n) {
        result[idx].x = data[idx].x + 10;
        result[idx].y = data[idx].y + 20;
    }
}
```

The file could be found at [gist](https://gist.github.com/fulltopic/96bf896488b0e6dcc29cedb95f3731a9)

Both cases were profiled by ncu-ui on *Quadro RTX 4000* and the `Memory Workload Analysis` is like

Performance without `__align__(8)`
[image: without align]

Performance with `__align__(8)`
[image: with align]

Why *L1 hit* of latter case is 0%? In my mind, the minimum granularity of load/store is *32 bytes* and *sizeof(InnerStruct)* is *8 bytes* with or without `__align__(8)` qualifier, the *InnerStruct.x* and *InnerStruct.y* would always be read in a same load with or without *L1 cache*. How `__align__` impacts the performance like this?

Comment: The pointers should be aligned at at least 128 Byte, if not 256 Byte Boundaries. You are probably reading and writing with the whole warp of 32 threads . The alignment decides, which instructions can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why L1 hit of latter case is 0%?

The `__align__(8)` directive allows the compiler to discover that it can convert 2 separate loads into a single load.  The result is that whereas in the non-decorated case, the compiler generates 2 loads, and the 2nd load derives benefit (cache hit rate) from the first load, in the decorated case, there *is only one load instruction*.  Therefore there is no observed cache benefit.

For the non-decorated case, the compiler does something like this:

```
if (idx < n) {
  //result[idx].x = data[idx].x + 10;
  LDG R0, [result[idx].x];  // pulls two 128-byte L1 cachelines per warp: MISS L1,MISS L2
  FADD R1, R0, 10;
  STG [result[idx].x], R1;  // HIT L2
  //result[idx].y = data[idx].y + 20;
  LDG R0, [result[idx].y];  // benefits from the L1 cache: HIT L1
  FADD R1, R0, 20;
  STG [result[idx].y], R1;  // HIT L2
}
```

For the decorated case, the compiler does something like:

```
if (idx < n) {
  LDG.64 R0,[result[idx].x];  // nothing populated cache prior to this: MISS L1,MISS L2
  //result[idx].x = data[idx].x + 10;
  FADD R0, R0, 10;
  //result[idx].y = data[idx].y + 20;
  FADD R1, R1, 20;
  STG.64 [result[idx].x], R0; // HIT L2
}
```

Thus there is only one load instruction, which does not get any cache benefit.

In the non-decorated case, the compiler cannot assume that the struct is aligned to 8 bytes.  It can only assume a 4-byte alignment (the natural alignment for `float` type).  If the struct *only* has 4 byte alignment (and not 8-byte alignment), then the LDG.64 instruction is not legal, because that instruction [requires](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) a "natural" 8-byte alignment.  Therefore in the non-decorated case, the compiler must use two 4-byte loads, because it cannot assume 8 byte alignment, whereas in the decorated case, it knows that LDG.64 is legal, and so it uses it instead.

(Aside: I suspect your GPU is not actually a Quadro 4000, but instead maybe a Quadro RTX 4000, because the Quadro 4000 was a [fermi-class GPU](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/quadro-4000.c898) which is not supported by any recent version of CUDA, much less nsight compute.)

Comment: Thank you, I've got the idea that the compiler combines instructions of `read InnerStruct.x` and `read InnerStruct.y` into one load.

Comment: Yes, my GPU is Quadro RTX 4000. I've updated my question description.